# Key error when accessing a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following list of nested dictionaries:

```py
raw_data = [
    {
        "type": "message",
        "subtype": "bot_message",
        "text": "This content can't be displayed.",
        "timestamp": "1650905606.755969",
        "username": "admin",
        "bot_id": "BPD4K3SJW",
        "blocks": [
            {
                "type": "section",
                "block_id": "BJNTn",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "You have a new message.",
                    "verbatim": False,
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "section",
                "block_id": "WPn/l",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "*Heard By*\nFriend",
                    "verbatim": False,
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "section",
                "block_id": "5yp",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "*Which Direction? *\nNorth",
                    "verbatim": False,
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "section",
                "block_id": "fKEpF",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "*Which Destination*\nNew York",
                    "verbatim": False,
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "section",
                "block_id": "qjAH",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "*New Customer:*\Yes",
                    "verbatim": False,
                },
            },
            # problem code chunk below
            {
                "type": "actions",
                "block_id": "yt4",
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "type": "button",
                        "action_id": "+bc",
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "bar": "View results",
                            "emoji": True,
                        },
                        "url": "www.example.com/results",
                    }
                ],
            },
            # problem code chunk above
            {
                "type": "section",
                "block_id": "IBr",
                "text": {"type": "mrkdwn", "text": " ", "verbatim": False},
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "type": "message",
        "subtype": "bot_message",
        "text": "This content can't be displayed.",
        "timestamp": "1650899428.077709",
        "username": "admin",
        "bot_id": "BPD4K3SJW",
        "blocks": [
            {
                "type": "section",
                "block_id": "Smd",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "You have a new message.",
                    "verbatim": False,
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "section",
                "block_id": "6YaLt",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "*Heard By*\nOnline Search",
                    "verbatim": False,
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "section",
                "block_id": "w3o",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "*Which Direction: *\nNorth",
                    "verbatim": False,
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "section",
                "block_id": "PTQ",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "*Which Destination? *\nMiami",
                    "verbatim": False,
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "section",
                "block_id": "JCfSP",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "*New Customer? *\nNo",
                    "verbatim": False,
                },
            },
            # problem code chunk below
            {
                "type": "actions",
                "block_id": "yt4",
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "type": "button",
                        "action_id": "+bc",
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "bar": "View results",
                            "emoji": True,
                        },
                        "url": "www.example.com/results",
                    }
                ],
            },
            # problem code chunk above
            {
                "type": "section",
                "block_id": "RJOA",
                "text": {"type": "mrkdwn", "text": " ", "verbatim": False},
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

My goal is to produce a Pandas dataframe that looks as follows:

```
    heard_by         direction   destination       new_customer
0   Friend           North       New York          Yes
1   Online Search    North       Miami             No
```

To do so, I use the following:

```
d_new = (pd.DataFrame([[re.sub(".*[*]\\W+", "", val['text']['text']) 
               for val in dat['blocks']] for dat in raw_data]).
          drop([0, 5], axis = 1))

d_new.columns = ['heard_by', 'direction','destination', 'new_customer']

d_new
```

Unfortunately, this throws a Key Error:

```
KeyError: 'text'
```

However, this code does work, but ***only if we comment out*** the following chunks in the list above:

```
#    {'type': 'actions',
#    'block_id': 'yt4',
#    'elements': [{'type': 'button',
#      'action_id': '+bc',
#      'text': {'type': 'plain_text', 'bar': 'View results', 'emoji': True},
#      'url': 'www.example.com/results'}]},
```

How do we adapt the code to handle this use case?

Thanks!

Comment: @ddejohn -- Are you suggesting to skip the "problem chunks" using `if dat["type"] != "actions"`  inside the call to `pd.DataFrame`?  Where does this line go?

Comment: See my answer. Should be `val["type"] != "actions"`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not grabbing anything from the "problem chunks", just skip them entirely:

```py
parsed = [[re.sub(".*[*]\\W+", "", val['text']['text']) for val in dat['blocks'] if val["type"] != "actions"] for dat in raw_data]

df_new = pd.DataFrame(parsed).drop([0, 5], axis=1)
d_new.columns = ['heard_by', 'direction','destination', 'new_customer']
```

Output:

```py
        heard_by direction destination new_customer
0         Friend     North    New York          Yes
1  Online Search     North       Miami           No
```

For what it's worth, when your comprehensions start getting this messy it's best to just write a standard `for` loop, which is much easier to understand and debug:

```py
parsed = []
for dat in raw_data:
    new_row = []
    for val in dat["blocks"]:
        if val["type"] != "actions":
            new_row.append(re.sub(".*[*]\\W+", "", val['text']['text'])
    parsed.append(new_row)
```

As an aside, how and where did you get these data? They're awfully inconsistent in format:

```
*Heard By*
Friend
*Which Direction? *
North
*Which Destination*
New York
*New Customer:*\Yes  # why is there a backslash here? Was it supposed to be '\n'?

*Heard By*
Online Search
*Which Direction: *
North
*Which Destination? *
Miami
*New Customer? *
No
```

Makes it very difficult to write a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try only keeping the data where "text" is one of the keys:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(data=[[re.sub(".*[*]\\W+", "", val['text']['text']) for val in dat['blocks'] if val.get('text')][1:5] for dat in raw_data],
                 columns=['heard_by', 'direction','destination', 'new_customer'])

        heard_by direction destination new_customer
0         Friend     North    New York          Yes
1  Online Search     North       Miami           No
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the problem chunks of code don't have a 'text' key, as their 'text' keys seem to be in the array value for the 'elements' key in those blocks. You may create a function that checks for the existence of the 'elements' or 'text' key and return the correct value accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of why the Key Error is being raised (because `[text][text]` does not match).  I was hoping to solve this without a function...